# TypeError occurs when I solve this system of equations

Tags: python, scipy, typeerror, sympy

```
from math import exp, log
from sympy import Symbol, symbols, solve, Eq
Z = 70;p_abs = 101.325*((1-2.25577*(10**-5)*Z)**5.2559);t_std = 15-0.0065*Z;RH = 0.5;t_db = 20
K_db = t_db + 273.15
C8 = -5.8002206e+03C9 = 1.3914993e+00;C10 = -4.8640239e-02;C11 = 4.1764768e-05;C12 = -1.4452093e-08;C13 = 6.5459673e+00
p_ws_db = exp(C8/K_db+C9+C10*K_db+C11*K_db**2+C12*K_db**3+C13*log(K_db))/1000
p_w_db = p_ws_db*RH # partial pressure of water vapor_db
W_s_db = 0.621945*p_ws_db/(p_abs-p_ws_db)
W_db = 0.621945*p_w_db/(p_abs-p_w_db)
p_w_wb = (W_db*p_abs)/(0.621945+W_db)
t_wb, K_wb, W_s_wb, p_ws_wb = symbols('t_wb K_wb W_s_wb p_ws_wb')
e1 = Eq(K_wb, t_wb + 273.15)
e2 = Eq(p_ws_wb, exp(C8/K_wb+C9+C10*K_wb+C11*K_wb**2+C12*K_wb**3+C13*log(K_wb))/1000)
e3 = Eq(W_s_wb, (W_db*((2501+1.86*t_db)-4.186*t_wb)+1.006*(t_db-t_wb))/(2501-2.326*t_wb))
e4 = Eq(p_ws_wb, (W_s_wb*p_abs)/(W_s_wb+0.621945))
print(fsolve([e1,e2,e3,e4], t_wb, p_ws_wb, K_wb, W_s_wb))
```

This is the code what have 4 equation and 4 unknowns. I am trying solving this equations by using sympy.solve. But it can't solve with an error;

```
TypeError: can't convert expression to float.
```

I guess exp or log create a problem.

Comment: Can you show the full traceback, instead of just that one line with `TypeError`?

Comment: sympy has its own exp and log functions. You can't mix functions in from other libraries to formulae that you manipulate with sympy. In your case, leave out that first line of code, and exp and log to the end of the import statement for sympy.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(fsolve([e1,e2,e3,e4], t_wb, p_ws_wb, K_wb, W_s_wb))
```

There is no `fsolve` in SymPy. There is `fsolve` in SciPy, a numeric solver. SciPy cannot work with SymPy objects, in particular it convert convert them to floats. Neither can `exp` and `log` that you imported from `math`.

Understand the difference between numeric computation and symbolic computation. If you want to compute `exp(a)` and `a` is a symbol, you need symbolic `exp` from SymPy, not a numeric `exp` from math or NumPy or somewhere else.

Correct import statements:

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, exp, log
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
```

Correct execution of numerical solution:

```
eqns = lambdify([t_wb, p_ws_wb, K_wb, W_s_wb], [e.lhs - e.rhs for e in [e1, e2, e3, e4]])    
print(fsolve(lambda x: eqns(*x), [10, 10, 10, 10]))
```

Here, [`lambdify`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) creates a function that SciPy can use, from the SymPy objects you have. It's a main tool for using SymPy objects in numeric modules. The created function takes four arguments, listed first, and returns four outputs, which are the difference between the left and right sides of each equation.

The initial vector `[10, 10, 10, 10]` is just a guess for solution, `fsolve` needs it as a starting point. The solution it finds is

```
[1.51295417e+03 7.10681717e+01 1.78610417e+03 1.50246122e+00]
```

Comment: thank you very much. It works!!! Although the solutions was quite different with the real solution at first, the solutions are correct after changing the initial vector!!! I understood that I had to solve with nonlinear equations rather than linear equations.

Comment: Indeed, when there are multiple solutions, the initial point determines which one will be found. So one tries to provide an initial point with coordinates of reasonable magnitude and sign, based on the understanding off the problem being solved.